# Created a new user on Xbian, now sudo prompt after each SSH login

Tags: ssh, sudo

I'm running the lastest Xbian on my Pi and created a new user on it. Whenever I log on to the Pi via SSH, the sudo prompt shows up right after the motd. It doesn't matter if that user is actually allowed to use sudo or not. If he's not, an error message appears after providing the password and nothing happens besides the bash prompt appearing. If the user is allowed to use sudo, the bash prompt appears right after entering the password.

The .profile and .bashrc are default and nothing in it requires sudo. Removing them also changes nothing. Deleting and adding the user again also doesn't help.

Does anyone know why the sudo prompt appears and how I can get rid of it?

---

It's a bug in the new release: http://forum.xbian.org/thread-168-post-2361.html#pid2361

Comment: I assume you have X installed? Have you customised it at all?

Comment: It's a plain Xbian installation. I guess X is preinstalled, but I haven't changed anything.

Comment: What do you mean by `The sudo prompt`?

Comment: XBian v1.0 comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.

!Importance notice!
rpi-update breaks core features of xbian, use it at your own risk

Last login: Sun Jan 13 10:32:48 2013 from SOMEMACHINE

[sudo] password for USERNAME:

Comment: Can you post that update as an answer? That was you can mark it answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in the latest release and has been reported. It will hopefully be fixed soon.

http://forum.xbian.org/thread-168-post-2361.html#pid2361
https://github.com/xbianonpi/xbian/issues/221